# How to make current page active using CSS?

Tags: wordpress, menu

How to make current page active? I would like to show active/hover color current page, which page I'm staying right now, like If I'm visited contact page then automatically show active/hover effect in the contact page menu item from the main/primary menu.
example http://prntscr.com/432y31.

I've tried this way but does not work: `.mainmenu .current_page_item a`
.mainmenu is my main/primary menu parent class.

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to help you, I think. We'd need to see your HTML as well as the definitions for your styles above. Can you prepare a JS Fiddle for us to see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you take a look at your source code?

Please make sure that `mainmenu` is a class. Maybe it's an id ...

So you can try this: `#mainmenu .current_page_item a`